# Cannot read property 'selectionEnd' of null using React + Jest + Datepicker + TextMask

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-datepicker

I had a unit test that was working, but now I added a new package to my `react-datepicker`, called `react-text-mask` and I tried to mock it, but it receive the following message when I run `npm run test`:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectionEnd' of null
>
> at Object.update (node_modules/react-text-mask/dist/reactTextMask.js:1:9205)
>
> at t.value (node_modules/react-text-mask/dist/reactTextMask.js:1:2431)
>
> at t.value (node_modules/react-text-mask/dist/reactTextMask.js:1:2490)
>
> at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6427:22)
>
> at commitAllLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7516:7)

My `react-datepicker` with `react-text-mask`:

```
<RCDatePicker
        {...rest}
        locale="pt-BR"
        selected={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        readOnly={readOnly}
        dateFormat={dateFormat}
        minDate={minDays ? moment(baseDate).subtract(minDays, 'days') : undefined}
        maxDate={maxDays ? moment(baseDate).add(maxDays, 'days') : undefined}
        disabled={disabled}
        customInput={<MaskedInput
          mask={[/[0-3]/, /\d/, '/', /[0-1]/, /\d/, '/', /[1-2]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
        />}
      >
```

My unit test:

```
describe('<DatePicker />', () => {
  it('should have default props', () => {
    const mock = jest.mock('react-text-mask', () => props => <input type="text" {...{ ...props }} />);
    const tree = renderer.create(<DatePicker onChange={Function} />).toJSON()
    jest.spyOn(mock)

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Comment: Where's the selectionEnd property?

Comment: Apparently, it's expected from `react-text-mask`, but I don't know how to insert that or mock. I've updated my error description, with the complete error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution, it was just put the mock outside the describe.

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { DatePicker } from './DatePicker'

jest.mock('react-text-mask', () => props => <input type="text" {...{ ...props }} />)

describe('<DatePicker />', () => {
  it('should have default props', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<DatePicker onChange={Function} />).toJSON()

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```